# wxRibbon shows but does not refresh or respond

Tags: wxwidgets

From the old style menus, I am trying to switch to ribbons. I have a wxMDIParentFrame which has two main children. Here is my attempt to switch to ribbons.

The code:

```
this->SetSizeHints( wxDefaultSize, wxDefaultSize );
m_StatusBar = this->CreateStatusBar( 2, wxST_SIZEGRIP, wxID_ANY );
wxMenuBar* m_MenuBar = new wxMenuBar( 0 ); //looks nonsense but I am getting warning messages because MDIParentFrame automatically adds a window menu
this->SetMenuBar(m_MenuBar);

wxBoxSizer* bSizer1;
bSizer1 = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

m_ribbonBar = new wxRibbonBar( this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxRIBBON_BAR_DEFAULT_STYLE );
m_ribbonBar->SetArtProvider(new wxRibbonDefaultArtProvider);
m_RibbonPage_Home = new wxRibbonPage( m_ribbonBar, wxID_ANY, wxT("Home") ,  wxBitmap( wxT("images/icons/open.bmp"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY ) , 0 );
m_ribbonPanelHome = new wxRibbonPanel( m_RibbonPage_Home, wxID_ANY, wxT("Document") , wxNullBitmap , wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxRIBBON_PANEL_DEFAULT_STYLE );
m_ribbonButtonBarDocument = new wxRibbonButtonBar( m_ribbonPanelHome, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
m_ribbonButtonBarDocument->AddButton( wxID_ANY, wxT("Open"), wxBitmap( wxT("images/icons/open.bmp"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY ), wxEmptyString);
    m_ribbonPageTools = new wxRibbonPage( m_ribbonBar, wxID_ANY, wxT("Tools") , wxNullBitmap , 0 );
m_ribbonBar->SetActivePage( m_ribbonPageTools );
m_ribbonPanelProcessEngTools = new wxRibbonPanel( m_ribbonPageTools, wxID_ANY, wxT("Process Engineering Tools") ,  wxBitmap( wxT("images/icons/open.bmp"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY ) , wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxRIBBON_PANEL_DEFAULT_STYLE );
m_ribbonButtonBar2 = new wxRibbonButtonBar( m_ribbonPanelProcessEngTools, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    m_ribbonButtonBar2->AddButton( wxID_ANY, wxT("Unit Convertor"),  wxBitmap( wxT("images/icons/open.bmp"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY ), wxEmptyString);

m_ribbonBar->Realize();


    // Connect Events
    this->Connect( wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, wxCloseEventHandler( myFrame::mainFrameOnClose ) );
    this->Connect( wxEVT_ICONIZE, wxIconizeEventHandler( myFrame::mainFrameOnIconize ) );
    this->Connect( wxEVT_IDLE, wxIdleEventHandler( myFrame::mainFrameOnIdle ) );
    this->Connect( wxID_ANY, wxEVT_COMMAND_RIBBONBAR_HELP_CLICKED, wxRibbonBarEventHandler( myFrame::OnRibbonBarHelpClick ) );
    this->Connect( wxID_ANY, wxEVT_COMMAND_RIBBONBAR_TAB_RIGHT_UP, wxRibbonBarEventHandler( myFrame::OnRibbonBarTabRightUp ) );
    this->Connect( wxID_ANY, wxEVT_COMMAND_RIBBONBAR_TOGGLED, wxRibbonBarEventHandler( myFrame::OnRibbonBarToggled ) );
    this->Connect( wxID_ANY, wxEVT_COMMAND_RIBBONBUTTON_CLICKED, wxRibbonButtonBarEventHandler( myFrame::OpenOnRibbonButtonClicked ) );
    this->Connect( wxID_ANY, wxEVT_COMMAND_RIBBONBUTTON_CLICKED, wxRibbonButtonBarEventHandler( myFrame::UCOnRibbonButtonClicked ) );


    #if wxUSE_STATUSBAR
    m_StatusBar->SetStatusText(_("Welcome..."), 0);
    m_StatusBar->SetStatusText(_(""), 1);
    #endif
    m_frmCmdWindow=new frmCommandWindow(this); //wxMDIChildFrame
    //m_frmCmdWindow->Show(true);

    m_frmICell=CreateFrmICell(this); //wxMDIChildFrame
    //m_frmICell->Show(true);
    int height=0, width=0;
    wxDisplaySize(&width,&height);
    this->SetSize(width,height);
    this->Tile();

    bSizer1->Add( m_ribbonBar, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND, 5 );
    this->SetSizer( bSizer1 );
    this->Centre( wxBOTH );
```

The appearance of the ribbon looks normal however following are the problems:
1) I can not interact with any of the buttons on the ribbon
2) It does not refresh (does not redraw itself).

*The ribbon is there as if there is a picture drawn and when I show any of the child frames the ribbon disappears.

3) wxMDIParentFrame has an automatic window menu attached to menubar to manage its child windows. How can I disable this window menu so that I can remove menubar.

By the way, I am using Windows 10, gcc 4.6.2 and wxWidgets 3.0.2.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanking you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me:

```
void MainFrame::CreateControls()
{    
////@begin MainFrame content construction
    // Generated by DialogBlocks, 18/10/2015 12:17:49 (unregistered)

    MainFrame* itemMDIParentFrame1 = this;

    wxStatusBar* itemStatusBar2 = new wxStatusBar( itemMDIParentFrame1, ID_STATUSBAR, wxST_SIZEGRIP|wxNO_BORDER );
    itemStatusBar2->SetFieldsCount(2);
    itemMDIParentFrame1->SetStatusBar(itemStatusBar2);

////@end MainFrame content construction

    wxBitmap tmp(16, 16);

    m_RibbonBar = new wxRibbonBar(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxRIBBON_BAR_DEFAULT_STYLE);
    m_RibbonBar->SetArtProvider(new wxRibbonDefaultArtProvider);

    auto m_RibbonPage_Home = new wxRibbonPage(m_RibbonBar, wxID_ANY, wxT("Home"), wxNullBitmap, 0);
    auto m_ribbonPageTools = new wxRibbonPage(m_RibbonBar, wxID_ANY, wxT("Tools"), wxNullBitmap, 0);

    auto m_ribbonPanelHome = new wxRibbonPanel(m_RibbonPage_Home, wxID_ANY, wxT("Document"), wxNullBitmap, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxRIBBON_PANEL_DEFAULT_STYLE);
    auto m_ribbonPanelProcessEngTools = new wxRibbonPanel(m_ribbonPageTools, wxID_ANY, wxT("Process Engineering Tools"), wxNullBitmap, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxRIBBON_PANEL_DEFAULT_STYLE);

    auto m_ribbonButtonBar2 = new wxRibbonButtonBar(m_ribbonPanelProcessEngTools, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);
    auto m_ribbonButtonBarDocument = new wxRibbonButtonBar(m_ribbonPanelHome, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0);

    m_ribbonButtonBarDocument->AddButton(wxID_NEW, wxT("Open"), tmp, wxEmptyString);
    m_RibbonBar->SetActivePage(m_ribbonPageTools);
    m_ribbonButtonBar2->AddButton(wxID_OPEN, wxT("Unit Convertor"), tmp, wxEmptyString);

    auto clientWindow = GetClientWindow();

    wxBoxSizer * sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    SetSizer(sizer);
    sizer->Add(m_RibbonBar, 0, wxGROW);
    sizer->Add(clientWindow, 1, wxEXPAND);


    m_RibbonBar->Realize();
}
```

[Here is the resulting frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEtfF.png)

Comment: It draws the ribbon but again it is not responsive and not refreshing. I might be wrong but unless the ribbon is on a childframe the ribbon does not work on a wxMDIParentFrame.

Comment: I used VS 2015 and it is responsive and buttons seem to be working. Could you try to build with MSVC and check whether it works better than with GCC? I will be able to test with GCC only in 2-3 days. Or, better, try to build a `ribbon` sample which comes in wxWidgets distro, with GCC and check whether it works for you. From what I can understand from your comment, this might be a compiler related bug.

Comment: Just to make sure that we are on the same page: Your frame (MainFrame) is an `wxMDIParentFrame` which should be, guessing from `GetClientWindow()`. The reason I am asking is I have tried drawing a `wxTextCtrl` on an `wxMDIParentFrame` and had the same problem as ribbon such that it showed but was not responsive neither auto refreshing.The ribbon well works for `wxMDIChildFrame` or `wxFrame`.

Comment: My `MainFrame` is `wxMDIParentFrame` (header: http://pastebin.com/zn8ugJdU, implementation: http://pastebin.com/F0YUUu7Y)

Comment: If you want to add anything to wxMDIParentFrame (wxTextCtrl or anything elase) then you need to create the sizer, add the desired control, then add the client window, then assign the sizer to a frame. What I can see from your code in initial post, you haven't added the client window to the sizer and it might be overlapping the other controls and prevents them from responding to user events (however they might paint correctly because have larger z-order)

Comment: I copied and pasted your code from pastebin, thanks a lot for your efforts; however, I should say it is working exactly the same way such that the ribbon is showing but the ribbon is not responding neither is it refreshing. By the way, without `Layout()` command, which I have added to the constructor right before `Center()` the ribbon is not even showing.

Comment: This indeed might be a compiler related issue. Could you build the sample which comes with wxWidgets and let me know whether it works fine for you? If it doesn't then would be good to submit a bug report.

Comment: I installed CodeBlocks with TDM 4.8 compiler suit. I tested the sample which comes along with wxWidgets, under CB + TDM it works very well.

Comment: Just slightly correcting myself. Yes, testing the sample works well. However, if I change the line in the sampe code from `wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)` to `wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxMDIParentFrame)`the ribbon does not work. I am not sure if this is a bug.

Comment: I think the bug comes with static event tables. On top of my previous comment, it seems that without declaring static event table, if I use `Connect` then the ribbon shows but does not work. However, if I declare `wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()` and either not declare or declare any event within the table, the ribbon works. Without declaring any event in static table, I can use `Connect` and it still works.

Comment: By the way, I am using Windows 10, GCC (tdm-2) 4.8.1 and wxWidgets 3.0.2.